# c# - web.api - try to build a new return value

Tags: c#, append

I'am learning c# and angular and I try to aggregate the data of a product with the follower. I have some NotMapped-fields in my class (codefirst)

```html
[NotMapped]
public string followitemtitle { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public string followitemprice { get; set; }
```

And I get 2 items of each group

```html
return _context.Product
.Include(c => c.productgroup)
.GroupBy(p => p.productgroupid)
.SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.productdate).Take(2));
```

What I try is a loop and build a new return-value -> only the first product ( every second in the list) - with some information of the follower product.

```html
        [HttpGet("new")]
        public IActionResult GetProductsIncFollower()
        {
            var productEntities = _productrepository.GetProductsIncFollower();

            Product tmpData = new Product();
            IEnumerable<Product> tmpDataList = new List<Product>();

            int index = 1;
            string tmpFollowtitle = "";
            string tmpFollowprice = "";

            foreach (var item in productEntities)
            {
                if(index % 2 != 0)  
                {
                    tmpFollowtitle = item.title;
                    tmpFollowprice = item.price;
                }

                else
                {
                    tmpData = item;
                    tmpData.followitemtitle = tmpFollowtitle;
                    tmpData.followitemprice = tmpFollowprice;
                    tmpDataList.Append(tmpData);
                }

                index++;
            }


            var results = tmpDataList;

            return Ok(results);
 }
```

But tmpDataList is empty and I dont understand why.

Comment: What is "Append" as far as I know, IEnumerable does not have Append method, is this your own extension method? You may wish to use List<Product> and use tmpDataList.Add(tmpData) instead of IEnumerable<Product>

Comment: Great, that was die Reason! I changed it to  List<Product> tmpDataList = new List<Product>(); and Add instead of Append and it work, great. Thank you!